# AIML how to check if the input string matches one from a map

Tags: aiml

I am trying to compare if the user's input matches the expected answer in AIML.  I found this code that works well when the value is true but, for some reason I can't understand, fails when the match is false (there is no match for the  and goes to UDC).  If it worked, I could easily replace the second * with my maps result.

From: https://github.com/pandorabots/aiml-utilities/blob/master/lib/aimlstandardlibrary.aiml

```
<!-- STRING EQUALS-->
<category>
    <pattern>XEQ * XS *</pattern>
    <template>
        <learn>
            <category>
                <pattern>
                    <eval>
                        <uppercase>XFALSE <star/></uppercase>
                    </eval>
                </pattern>
                <template>TRUE</template>
            </category>
        </learn>
        <srai>XFALSE <star index="2"/></srai>
        <learn>
            <category>
                <pattern>
                    <eval>
                        <uppercase>XFALSE <star/></uppercase>
                    </eval>
                </pattern>
                <template>FALSE</template>
            </category>
        </learn>
    </template>
</category>
```

Does anyone have a better way to do it?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the entire library AIML file? You need this category for it to work (it's at the top of the file):

```
<category>
  <pattern>
  XFALSE *
  </pattern>
  <template>FALSE</template>
</category>
```

Without it, the UDC will be called. A more efficient method would be to use the condition tag. This removes the need to use the <learn> tag to set up extra categories:

```
<category>
    <pattern>XEQ * XS *</pattern>
    <template>
        <think>
            <set name="value1"><star/></set>
            <set name="value2"><star index="2"/></set>
        </think>
        <condition name="value1">
            <li><value><get name="value2"/></value>TRUE</li>
            <li>FALSE</li>
        </condition>
    </template>
</category>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve.  You're right I hadn't included the entire library, and I certainly find your solution easier to understand.  I tested it and works fine.